# Derivative of a squared definite integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

Differentiation of
$\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)\,\text{d}t$ is done by Leibniz's integral rule:
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \left (\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)\,\text{d}t \right )= f\big(x,b(x)\big)\cdot \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} b(x) - f\big(x,a(x)\big)\cdot \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} a(x) + \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,t) \,\text{d}t,$$

if $-\infty<a(x),b(x)<\infty$.

Can we say anything in general about the derivative of the powers of the $\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)\,\text{d}t$ in a similar fashion? So for example
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \left(\left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)\,\text{d}t\right)^2\right)=~?$$

Comment: I commend you on a very nice first question which meets all of our community standards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By chain rule

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \left(\left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)\,\text{d}t\right)^2\right)=2\left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)\,\text{d}t\right)\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)\,\text{d}t\right)$$

Comment: Is this still the case if I integrate with respect to $x$?

Comment: How would you define the integration with respect to x?

Comment: Let's say we only consider $f$ as a single variable function $f(x)$, so that we seek $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \left(\left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x)\,\text{d}x\right)^2\right)$$ or maybe to avoid confusion $$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x} \left(\left(\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(s)\,\text{d}s\right)^2\right).$$

Comment: Ah ok, the second version with the s as variable of integration is fine. The first one shouldn’t be well defined.

Comment: I was very well aware of the chain rule though, however I wasn't sure if I could apply it in this case. It didn't seem trivial. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: Since the integral is a differentiable function of x, chain rule applies, there are not exceptions! You are welcome! Bye

Answer (score 3):

Hint: According to Chain rule,
$$\frac{d}{dx} (y^n) = ny^{n-1}\frac{d}{dx}(y).$$